# How to get the UNNEST in bigquery to unnest rows but keep some fields in one row only

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, case

i have my inpt table like this

[image]

i want to get the expected output like this.

[image]

i tried below query like this and i got like this but notes and fru fields i need in only one row like above expected output

```
select parent,child,name,notes,fru 
from plm-wave-dev.data_migration_sandbox.ref_des_not_empty,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, qty))
```

[image]

please letme know is there any way to get the output like i am expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach using the array generator to create the correct number of rows looks good. You can use `case` expressions on the generated series of values to implement the logic you want:

```
select parent, child, name, 
    case when n = 1 then notes end as notes,
    case when n = 1 then fru   end as fru
from plm-wave-dev.data_migration_sandbox.ref_des_not_empty
cross join unnest(generate_array(1, qty)) as n
```